# Tricky situation with serializing and deserializing transient objects

Tags: java, serialization, transient

Here's my code:

```
class Collar {
  int size;
}

class Dog implements Serializable {
  int weight;
  transient Collar c;

  public Dog(int weight, int size) {
    this.weight = weight;
    c = new Collar();
    c.size = size;
  }

  public void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os) throws Exception {
    os.defaultWriteObject();
    os.writeInt(c.size);
  }

  public void readObject(ObjectInputStream is) throws Exception {
    is.defaultReadObject();
    c = new Collar();
    c.size = is.readInt();
  }
}

public class test {
  public static final String FILE_REVISION = "$Revision$";

  public static void main(String ar[]) throws Exception {
    Dog dOut = new Dog(20, 2);

    System.out.println("DOut Weight: " + dOut.weight + " Size: " + dOut.c.size);

    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("Dog.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);
    os.writeObject(dOut);

    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("Dog.ser");
    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
    Dog dIn = (Dog) is.readObject();

    System.out.println("DIn Weight: " + dIn.weight + " Size: " + dIn.c.size);
  }
}
```

and here's the output:

```
DOut Weight: 20 Size: 2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.main(test.java:55)
```

Line 55 is the last line of code that has System.out.println()

The program is able to get back the serializable object, which is Dog here.  However, its not able to create a new 'containment' object, Collar, when I'm reading back using custom readObject method.  Where am I going wrong?

As you can see the output is NullPointerException in 'dIn.c.size' statement.  Even though I'm setting up c as a new object in custom readObject method, it's not working really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Collar c` is `transient` inside `readObject` you need to initialize `c` First

```
c.size = is.readInt();<-- NullPointerException Here
```

Here you need to initialize `C` first.

```
c = new Collar();
c.size = is.readInt();
```

**Both method signatures are wrong they should be like below:**

```
 private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream stream) throws IOException {
    stream.defaultWriteObject();
    stream.writeInt(c.size);
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream stream) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    stream.defaultReadObject();
    c = new Collar();
    c.size = stream.readInt();
}
```

You can read more details about Serialization [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html)

Comment: You mean I should initialize while declaring the object in the class?  I thought that's a bad design.  Is there no other workaround?  This example is taken from Kathy's SCJP book.  But it doesn't work.

Comment: It is not bad design you need to understand how serialization works. As this variable is transient inside readObject you need to do same what you do in constructor.

Comment: My bad.  I thought you are talking about initializing c while declaring it.  So, what you and the other user suggested, I have done it already.  Accidentally I did 'undo' too many times and missed that line, before copying.  Even when I have initialized c before assigning its member the value read back in readObject, it doesn't work.  The main question is updated, thank you.

Comment: Perfect!  Yes, they have to be private, not public.  Thank you very much.

I'm trying to vote for your answer, but I'm a new user, so I am not allowed to.  Your answer solves this question.

Comment: AmitD is right: the problem is that the signatures of the methods are wrong, so they are not being called at all. For what it's worth, the important things about the signatures are the name, the types of the parameters, and the visibility, which must be protected. The throws list doesn't actually seem to matter.

Comment: @narayanf1: You can still accept the answer, even if you can't upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `Collar` member in `readObject` method

```
public void readObject(ObjectInputStream is) throws Exception {
    is.defaultReadObject();
    c = new Collar();
    c.size = is.readInt();
}
```

**EDIT:**
 The `Serializable` methods need to be changed to private.

Comment: I'm sorry my bad.  I did an undo accidentally before copying the code.  So, NO, it doesn't work even then.  I'll update the main question with what you have suggested.  Thank you.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  And that's what is making me feel it's a tricky situation.  The code is ready to be copied and compiled to check in your machine (you just need to add the import statements).